# Scrape a php webpage that needs a submitted form

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

Here is the link- http://armstrade.sipri.org/armstrade/page/values.php

I'm trying to write a Python code to automatically download these CSV files for each state in the drop down menu. The code I have is as following:

```
submit_value={'country_code':'ALG','low_year':'2010','high_year':'2018','import_or_export':'import','summarize':'country','filetype':'html','Action':'Download'}
page = requests.post(url='http://armstrade.sipri.org/armstrade/page/values.php',data=submit_value)
```

However, this does not give me anything new. Rather, the content I have in page.text is exactly the same as the original HTML page. This suggests that all those parameters (year range, country code, etc...) are not submitted to the page.

Any idea how could I get this done? Much appreciated!!

Comment: Souldn't the URL be `http://armstrade.sipri.org/armstrade/html/export_values.php`?

Comment: when I open the page from the official website of SIPRI, the link is 
http://armstrade.sipri.org/armstrade/page/values.php, it will change to the one you indicated if I actually submit a form and show the data on screen

Comment: I guess you're right and this is the essential part that prevents me from getting the right result. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already almost there. Check requests & responses (ex., in Network tab of Chrome's tools)

```
submit_value={'country_code':'ALG','low_year':'2010','high_year':'2018','import_or_export':'import','summarize':'country','filetype':'html','Action':'Download'}
response = requests.post(url='http://armstrade.sipri.org/armstrade/html/export_values.php',data=submit_value)
with open("/tmp/sample.hmtl", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

Worked just fine!

**UPD:**
(Decided to highlight due to typo in my answer)

1. It is **html/export_values**.php, request should go there
2. `response.text` contains data (it could be `response.content` as well, just bytes there)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ran your code but the 'sample.hmtl' file actually states:
<!-- body -->
 <p class="page404">Page not found</p>

did you verify your file?

Comment: @Xyt, I did. There was a typo, fixed my answer -- it is `html/export_values.php`

Comment: This is right solution. I run by self and can get output html.

Comment: Thanks! I re-ran and get the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GET request instead of a POST request, as you are not inputting any values, rather you are requesting some data from the client.

Comment: I tried both POST and REQUEST actually, get the same result. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your script working very good. page.content hold all response data. Thanks.

```html
import requests
submit_value={'country_code':'ALG','low_year':'2010','high_year':'2018','import_or_export':'import','summarize':'country','filetype':'html','Action':'Download'}
page = requests.post(url='http://armstrade.sipri.org/armstrade/page/values.php',data=submit_value)
print(page.content)
```

Comment: I don't think so, the content I have gives me nothing but the original page where you could submit your form. Did you verify your result?